# How to create a public static library which relies on a private static library in XCode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, static-libraries

My company would like to offer two different SDKs for iOS development along with a sample application which uses each.  Both SDKs make use of a lot of common code which isn't part of the public interface of either SDK.

I'd like to structure the projects so that I have our common code in one static library framework (which we keep private), and have each SDK is its own static library framework (which we'd publish).  The SDK frameworks each depend on on the common framework.

I've pretty much got this set up and working, except for one thing...  There are a few parent classes in the common library which are used in the SDK code.  In order to publish the subclasses in the SDK code, I need to export the headers for the parent class (which is only in the private, common framework) along with the SDK framework.

---

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?  Here are the most important priorities:

- Customers can download a single framework and have it just work
- We don't duplicate code across multiple projects

Comment: Not totally sure what your problem is, is it that you'd rather not publish the headers for the parent classes?

Comment: No, I don't mind doing that.  The problem is that I *can't get* XCode to include them in the SDK framework.

Comment: Did  you ever get this to work? How would the customers get one of the public frameworks to build if they aren't provided with the private one? Are you linking the common framework into the public frameworks' binaries?

If so, what if SDK A is using CommonSDK 1.0 and SDK B is using CommonSDK 1.1? Would you have problems linking both of these into the same app?

Answer (score 0):

Having a class with a higher visibility than its ancestors is a tough problem. In fact, some very popular languages and runtimes prohibit it (like languages that use the .NET Framework).

There is no obvious solution. The easiest, in my opinion, is to publish headers for the private classes with only the fields. The methods can be omitted. This is how "private" methods are hidden in Apple frameworks (that would basically make the class "public", but all methods would be hidden).

Another solution would be to use composition rather than inheritance to get the features. Make your public classes inherit from `NSObject`, and give them an instance of your private class (hide its type with an `id` field).

Comment: To clarify a bit... I'm not too worried about exposing the headers for the parent classes; what I'm more concerned about is not exposing everything in the common framework.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to configure the SDK's XCode project so that it will copy over the headers I need from the common framework into the SDK's framework.

Comment: @AndrewMiner, what is the exact setup? Are you publishing `.framework` objects or `.a` objects with a bunch of headers? I get confused with `static frameworks`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to add those common header files to both frameworks as references in Xcode. An Xcode project file can reference files external to that project folder. You can then choose to publish them using the Copy Header Files build phase.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this my blogpost.

Click [here](http://iphonedevelopent.blogspot.com/)

This is the complete reference for creation a static library.

Comment: This is "Completely" wrong. It solves a different problem, badly.